# Upload file FTP before root folder C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file via FTP, I need to upload it before the root folder.
With my code the file is uploaded but in the root and not before as I need.

```
FtpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            completePath = completePath.TrimEnd('/');
            filename = filename.TrimStart('/');
            completePath = completePath.TrimEnd('\\');
            filename = filename.TrimStart('\\');
            completePath = completePath + "/" + filename;

            Uri pathUri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.29.2/%2E%2E/test1234.txt");


            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathUri);
            if (request == null)
            {
                //result.SetError(Translate.InvalidUrl, completePath);
                return false;
            }
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            //request.Timeout = 5000;

            request.Proxy = null;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftp_admin", "ftp_admin");

            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            fileContents.CopyTo(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();


        }
```

Does someone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: before the root folder? i dont know if such thing exists. isn't it like going back before big bang?

Answer (score 2):

You can't navigate below the root folder in the FTP address. If that was allowed, you could navigate into some other users folder, or into the system files of the server.

For the FTP address there exists no such place, and there might not even exist anything below the FTP root folder on the disk. The FTP account could for example be set up to use `D:\` as root folder.